# Add extra column to WPF DataGrid which is not in the collection

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid, datatable

I'm using a DataGrid control to display content of a DataTable. Therefore the data table is set as ItemsSource of DataGrid.

Following columns of the DataGrid represent columns of the data table:

Type, Name, Domain, Subdomain

Now the dynamic column, called "Properties" should contain specific information, depending on the value of the "Type" column.
Something like this:

```
switch (Type)
    case ABC:   content="row.Field1"
    case DEF:   content="row.Field2"
    case XYZ:   content="row.FieldX"
```

Where Field1 .. FieldX are all columns from the data table.
I'm currently using a DataGrid together with a BindingListCollectionView.
Best if the solution would build up on this.

I tried with multivalue binding and a multivalue converter but I would like to have more freedom and not having to pre-select the fields:

```
var bind = new MultiBinding();

bind.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Protocol"));
bind.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Path1"));
bind.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Path2"));
bind.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Path3"));
bind.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Path4"));

bind.Converter = _ConfigurationMultiValueConverter;

col.Binding = bind;
```

Comment: You should use ValueConverter [link](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) here is an example. And inside converter, switch to proper field

Comment: I was also trying this but I don't know how to address the DataRow object inside the converter method to access the proper field (column). Currently I'm trying with a Multivalue converter, giving a set of fields to the converter. But it's not very satisfying and I would prefer being able to access all fields of the data row from the converter function, not only selected.

Comment: You could pass whole data object into value converter. Show ua some code.

Comment: Yes, I've also tried to do this, with no success. I tried to do it with the binding. But I couldn't figure out how to bind to the whole data row of data table.

Comment: Could you paste some code, how yo do this ?

Comment: How do I paste code as a comment?

Comment: Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work

Comment: I've edited the question and added code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like that. Of course it's only an example.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public YourType Protocol;
    public YourType2 Path1;
    public YourType3 Path2;
    public YourType4 Path3;
    public YourType5 Path4;
    public int ChooseExpression;
    public YourType6 Field1;
    public YourType7 Field3;
    public YourType8 FieldX;
}
```

and then in your DataGrid

```
<DataGrid Name="IfYouNeedAName" AutoGennerateColumn="False" ItemsSource={Binding YourClass} >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ProtocolHeader" Binding={Binding Protocol} />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Path1Header" Binding={Binding Path1} />
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="TheChoosenOne" Binding={Binding YourClass, YourBindingConverer} />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and at last the converter, which inherit by IValueConverter

```
public class YourBindingConverer : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch(value.ChooseExpression)
            case 1: return Field1.ToString();
            case 2: return Field3.ToString();
            case 3: return FieldX.ToString();
        else
            return string.Empty;
        end;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I've wrote it from my memory, becasue I don't have VS here. But I think, it could be something like that.
If you have more questions, feel free to ask.

And for bonus, [here](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) is good solution for value converters.

Comment: I'm using the powerful mechanism of .NET's DataSet architecture, where the DataTable instance is directly bound to the DataGrid view. The values are coming from the data table behind. I don't want to break out from this architecture and do everything else manually. I'm looking for a way to customize the view, following the architecture. Otherwise I would lose all the benefits that architecture offers me.